# Jasmine test to test javascript uploading files in web browser

Tags: javascript, html, jasmine, ecmascript-6

I want to create a `jasmine` test for a `javascript` program that uploads a file in a web browser and checks if the file has content. Here is the code:

```js
function test(filePath) {
  var file = filePath.files[0];
  var reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onloadend = () => {
    if(reader.result == "") {
      display.innerText = 'has nothing';
    } else {
        display.innerText = 'has something';
    }
  }
  reader.readAsText(file);
}

window.onload = () => {
  var filePath = document.getElementById('filePath');
  var display = document.getElementById('display');

  filePath.addEventListener('change', () => {
    test(filePath);
  });
}
```

```html
<input id="filePath" type="file">
<pre id="display"></pre>
```

How do I write the `jasmine` test using sample files?

Answer (score 0):

Basically here need to mock the file path,assuming that file already uploaded,

var  mockPath = "/aaa/bbb/ccc.doc";  //which is the local file path

&& Call the test function from the spec file

&& expect the asserts that file has some text or not by verifying the reader object.

Note: Here need to mock the reader object as well.

Comment: if i user the file path as the argument for the function, nothing is displayed meaning the file input is not a string of the file path; so what object if the file input?

Comment: If it's a literal, you need to escape the backslashes before Javascript sees them; there's no way around that.

var newpath = 'file:///C:\\xxxx\\yyyy\\zzzz.txt';                                         newpath.replace(/\\/g,"\\\\");  try this if path is not taking as a string param

Comment: it doesn't work. and could you please explain the replace function

Comment: can anyone please help

Answer (score 0):

try this one for passing the path and use escape function for path

```
var str="/Users/zzz/Desktop/testFile.txt";
var str_esc=escape(str);
document.write(str_esc + "<br>");
function readData(filePath){
   console.log("<br>"+filePath);
   var reader = new FileReader();
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/92698vka/